# Strip tags from a the terms() function

Tags: custom-taxonomy, php

Trying to print my custom post type's taxonomy but without the link. Tried this, but doesn't seem to work, any suggestions?

```
$text = the_terms($post->ID,'type','','',''); 
echo strip_tags($text);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm about to start punching babies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use a filter and `strip_tags()`, as you suggested. Example using post tags, since that's the taxonomy I had available:

```
function my_remove_links( $term_links ) { 
    return array_map('strip_tags', $term_links);
}
add_filter('term_links-post_tag', 'my_remove_links');
```

Really though, I would just [`get_the_terms()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/category-template.php#L898) and and craft the output yourself:

```
function the_simple_terms() {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID,'post_tag','',', ','');
    $terms = array_map('_simple_cb', $terms);
    return implode(', ', $terms);
}   

function _simple_cb($t) {
    return $t->name;
}

echo the_simple_terms();
```

Comment: you are incredible that you so much, I ended up using the second option. beautiful.

Answer (score 1):

the_terms() echos the output and returns null.  So your first line is echoing the terms with the anchor tags and then your echoing null in the second line.  You want to use get_the_terms().